# How do I switch the flag with my current code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently using the following code for my language flag

```
<a href="#" onclick="change_lang()"><i class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb></i></a>
```

My Javascript is

```
var dictionary = {
    'greet': {
        'it': 'Ciao',
        'en': 'Hello',
        'fr': 'Salut',
    }
};
var langs = ['it', 'en', 'fr'];
var current_lang_index = 0;
var current_lang = langs[current_lang_index];

window.change_lang = function() {
current_lang_index = ++current_lang_index % 3;
current_lang = langs[current_lang_index];
translate();
}

function translate() {
$("[data-translate]").each(function(){
    var key = $(this).data('translate');
    $(this).html(dictionary[key][current_lang] || "N/A");
});
}

translate();
```

Which can be found on https://jsfiddle.net/x93oLad8/4/

How do I change flag-icon-gb to flag-icon-cn perhaps using the same javascript?

Comment: `using the same javascript` - clearly you need new javascript because the current javascript doesn't come close ... hint: elements have `className` property

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you for the respond. Can you give me a sample or tell me how to do it please :( I'm not really good with Javascript :(

Comment: Or is there a way where I can add the change the <i> tag into the js 'it': <i></i>?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I was way off on my first answer but I see you have updated your fiddle so I have some more context

I've added div to your HTML and whenever the language gets switched the language value also gets added as a class to the div. CSS is then used to add a background image which has all the flags on it and it's positioned differently (showing a different flag) depending on the class currently added to the element (based on `current_lang`)

Don't worry about the huge data URI in the fiddle, I didn't have a background image to use to I made one and converted it to a data URI - you can just use an actual picture (if you want) or stick with the data URI

So I added to the HTML:

```
<div id="langflag"></div>
```

You can add the id (or change it to a class) to anything and put a background image on it - just be sure to add some padding so that there's some background space that won't get covered.

And then I added a line to your js to change the class on the div:

```
function translate() {
    $("[data-translate]").each(function(){
        var key = $(this).data('translate');
        $(this).html(dictionary[key][current_lang] || "N/A");
        $("#langflag").attr('class', current_lang); // this is new
    });
}
```

And then added the styles that add the background image and change the position based on the classes:

```
#langflag {
  height: 20px;
  width: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  background-color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("yourpic.png");
}
#langflag.it { background-position: 0 0; }
#langflag.en { background-position: -32px 0; }
#langflag.fr { background-position: -64px 0; }
```

you can use the data uri as the picture - ugly but efficient!:

```
background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
```

See fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ppppz1gL/

You could also add an actual image and update the src attribute in the script but a single background image (one http request) and especially a data URI (no http requests) is more efficient (despite the large chunk of text which is pretty light in the scheme of things (images are probably how most people could reduce the size of their sites - it's so easy to not bother though - I'm guilty!))

I hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. I'll give it a shot and see if it works. What do you mean by pass a reference to     'this'  in inline click handler?

Comment: Or is there a way where I can add the change the <i> tag into the js 'it': <i></i>?

Comment: @HELLOHK I've updated my answer - I hope it helps, let me know.

Comment: @HELLOHK if it helped could you mark it as correct or give me some advice on how I could improve it?